# How can I make a PHP counter?

Tags: php, count, counter

I know I have done this in Javascript once, but how can I make it in PHP?
Basically I want to do this:

```
if (empty($counter)){
   $counter = 1;
}else{
   "plus one to $counter" ($counter++?)
}
```

But it didn't work when I tried. How would I go about doing this?

Thank you :)

EDIT: This is so I can do:

```
if ($counter == 10){
   echo("Counter is 10!");
}
```

EDIT:

This is all in a "while()" so that I can count how many times it goes on, because LIMIT will not work for the query I'm currently doing.

Comment: What do you mean by it didn't work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

why the extra if into the while?
i would do this:

```
$counter = 0;
while(...)
{
    (...)
    $counter++;
}

echo $counter;
```

Answer (score 4):

To increment a given value, attach the increment operator `++` to your integer variable and place it within your while loop directly, without using a conditional expression to check if the variable is set or not.

```
$counter = 1;

while(...){
    echo "plus one to $counter";
    $counter++;
}
```

If your counter is used to determine how many times your code is to be executed then you can place the condtion within your `while()` expression:

```
while($counter < 10){
    echo "plus one to $counter";
    $counter++;
}

echo("Counter is $counter!");  // Outputs: Counter is 10!
```

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to learn the basics of how PHP outputs to the screen and the other controls along with it.

```
if (empty($counter)){
   $counter = 1;
}else{
   echo 'plus one to $counter';
   $counter++;
}
```

Something along those lines will work for you.

PHP is pretty flexible with what you throw at it.  Just remember, statements need a semicolon at the end, and if you want to output to the screen, (in the beginning) you'll be relying on `echo` statements.

Also, when dealing with `echo` statements, notice the difference between single quotes and double quotes.  Double quotes will process any contained variables:

```
$counter = 3;
echo "plus one to $counter"; // output: plus one to 3
echo 'plus one to $counter'; // output: plus one to $counter
```

Comment: The echo was just to explain. I know PHP basics, this was just a quick post so that I could fix my function.

Comment: Gotcha.  Just wanted to help kick-start you if you didn't know. (: