# How To Div Number's ul into a loop?

Tags: html, wordpress

I am not so expert. I am trying to modify "Category post Widget". In the loop, I want html output like that.

```
 <ul>

 <li><div class="a">1</div>
 Title here
 </li>
 <li><div class="a">2</div>
 Title here
 </li>
 <li><div class="a">2</div>
 Title here
 </li>
 </ul>
```

My loop is:

```
    echo '<ol>';

    while ( $cat_posts->have_posts() )
    {
        $cat_posts->the_post();
    ?>
        <li>
            <a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?> Apk Android Download"><font color="#000"><?php the_title(); ?></font></a>


        </li>
    <?php 
    } 
         ?>
        </ol>
```

Suppose this widget has 10 item. How can I number (with div) those 10 items?
PS: I found some wp blog have done this. [epdroid.com](http://epdroid.com) is one of them.

Comment: What happens when you use your code above?

Comment: it simply display ul list without number. I want to numbering that list And those number will be within a div

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using an `ol` instead of `ul`? Which will number the list for you without the need for the `div`.

Comment: The main reason I want ul than ol is that div. I want <div>number here</div>

Comment: Can you post a but more of the code? Specifically what is after the </li>?

Comment: why do you need the div? If the number is just going to increment by one then semantically you should be using an `ol` but if you are deadset on having it then use a counter like in the [accepted answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869142/how-can-i-make-a-php-counter)

Comment: @Howlin. Ops a singel code (though not needed for this issue) was missing. I added after <li>.

Comment: @Pete I want div to design. You can say I can design numbers of <ol>. But Adding A div is more comforting with mobile device and some other issue.

Comment: Dont make others confuse please. What you need finally?

Comment: You should use a [css counter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters) and `:before` on the `li` then if it is just for design purposes, which will allow you to use an ol keeping the structure correct - http://jsfiddle.net/739t8ypy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you open the  outside the while loop but you keep closing it inside the while loop try this code:

```
echo '<ol>';
$i = 0;
while ( $cat_posts->have_posts() )
{
    $cat_posts->the_post();
?>
    <li><div class="a"><?php echo $i++ + 1; ?> </div>
        <a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?> Apk Android Download"><font color="#000"><?php the_title(); ?></font></a>
    </li>
<?php } //end of the while loop ?>
    </ol>
```

Comment: Yes bro.... That fix my problem.   <?php echo $i; $i++; ?> is the thing i needed. Can You help a little bit? how to remove bullets?

Comment: Check Pete comment for the jsfiddle.net/739t8yoy

Comment: A little bug in Solution. If I  use your <?php echo $i; $i++; ?> then it star 1st <li> as "no value", second is 1, 3rd is 2 ..... And to make first value 1 I use this <?php echo $i++ + 1; ?> And it is fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @SyKat, I didn't checked that before posting.